# Rails activerecord to_sql_string?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've seen somewhere but can not remember. How to get a SQL string from an ActiveRecord object?

```
Client.find(1).to_sql_string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you where looking at [arel](http://rdoc.info/projects/rails/arel), which has a nice `to_sql`

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 3 you can use `to_sql` method

```
Client.first.to_sql
#=> some raw sql
```